# DB2 10.1 Client throws SQL0552N running a script

Tags: db2

I am trying to run a sql script on a remote database using DB2 10.1 on AIX 6.1.  I have granted my admin user (Adm101) on the database server SECADM. But when i run my script on the remote server with the db2 client (Client101) I get:

```
SQL0552N "Client101" does not have the privilege to perform operation "CREATE TABLE". SQLSTATE=42502
```

Adm101 is in listed in the database but Client101 is not.  How can I create a table on the remote client?

Comment: I think you should do a little reading to understand what privileges `SECADM` gets, as opposed to `SYSADM`, etc.  See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0055206.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to grant Client101 CONNECT and CREATETAB on database in order to be able to create a table. It may also help to grant IMPLICIT_SCHEMA as well. And depending on the version of your client, you may either need to connect with an admin ID first, or grant BINDADD to your ID so it can bind version specific system packages.

```
db2 connect to mydb as admin101 using "password"
db2 grant connect,createtab,implicit_schema,bindadd on database to user client101
db2 connect reset
```

then

```
db2 connect to mydb as client101 using "other_password"
db2 create table .....
```